# Java REST using DataSource

Tags: java, rest, jdbc

I'm new to REST on Java and I would like to create "simple" REST services that queries a database and returns some JSON info.

What I would like is to use JDBC access to DB, no JPA.

When working with servlets I configure a server  datasource and in my servlets in the "init()" method I store a reference to the datasource and on every request create a connection.

What must I do for REST services?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are planning to connect via JDBC based on the REST API requests and already familiar with REST, you should consider looking into Spring JDBC support: [Current JDBC Spring Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html). This would take care of all your concerns regarding the right place and time of instantiating/looking up a data source or connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to maintain my code as lightweight as possible. Only want to know how and where initialize JDBC connection. Thanks.

Comment: If your application has more than a handful of exposed service methods, you would soon drown in all try/catch/finally blocks required to maintain connections. I would argue that a code that separates concerns and, even better, offloads the routine ones on a framework is the lightweight code.

Comment: +1: Using Spring will be far more lightweight--and more correct--than managing JDBC connections yourself.